# Makefile to archive/link together auto-generated source files

Tags: automation, dependencies, makefile

Basically, I have a file 'blah.txt'. That files gets parsed by a 'compiler' and from it will generate N output .c files. I want a makefile that will from that .txt file generate the c files then compile all of them and archive them in a libmystuff.a

I tought of something like this :

```
all: dogen libmystuff.a

dogen: source.txt
    mycompiler $^

libmystuff.a: $(addsuffix .o, $(shell ls *.c))
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^

.PHONY: dogen
```

But obviously that doesn't work because the dependencies are evaluated at the start and at that point the *.c just doesn't yield anything yet since they don't exist.

Does anyone see how to accomplish that (without listing all the generated *.c explicitely) ?

Comment: Please, specify [make] tag instead of [makefile].  For more info, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/why-do-they-specify-makefile-tag-instead-of-make/26567#26567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavel Shved is right(*), you must rerun Make. Here is a trick I'm rather proud of. It will handle dependencies on objects that may not yet exist, and won't run unnecessarily.

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: libmystuff.a

ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),0) 
libmystuff.a: source.txt
    mycompiler $^ 
    @$(MAKE) -s $@
else
libmystuff.a: $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^ 
endif
```

(*) My old nemesis, we meet again.

**EDIT:**
If some *other* make calls *this* make... I hadn't thought of that. But I think this will solve it:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: libmystuff.a

libmystuff.a: source.txt
    mycompiler $^ 
    @$(MAKE) -s phonyLib

.PHONY: phonyLib
phonyLib: $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) rcs libmystuff.a $^
```

(Yes, I know, if you feel an urge to build a file called "phonyLib" you won't be able to do it with this makefile, but let's not be perverse.)

Comment: Oh, I wont nitpick on *that*!  Rather, I'd do ... oh, never mind :)

Comment: You've been in this forum half as long as I have and won four times the reputation, AND English isn't your native language, so try to fight back the bitter tears.

Comment: But knowing `make` is really the thing I'm proud of... was, actually. :-)  Anyway, these discussions really improved my knowledge.  Particularly, I should revamp my approach to recursive `make` invocation vs. including dummy makefiles. (And now I'll be shy trying to comment your posts in English.)

Comment: Oh, for the love of... Your English is fine (and if I tried commenting in Russian, nobody would be able to read it, including Russians). And I thought I knew all about Make until I started reading your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use sentry "makefile" to force make to re-read makefile and substitute correct list at `*.c`:

```
include sources-sentry

sources-sentry: source.txt
    mycompiler $^
    touch $@

libmystuff.a: $(addsuffix .o, $(shell ls *.c))
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^
```

`include` directive is used to include other makefiles (just like C's `#include`).  It has a nice pecularity that if makefile it includes is a target itself, `make` program first considers it as a target and tries to update.  If it is not up-to-date, make invokes the commands needed to update it and then **re-reads makefile, substituting all the variables again**.

Thus, if source.txt changed since the last time you processed it (the time being recorded as timestamp of sources-sentry **file**), the sources will be updated and make will be re-invoked, the `*.c` being substituted to the updates set of c-files.

Comment: Works great, just one problem tough: When I make the clean target, it builds the thing too ...

Comment: @246tNt , you are right, and I don't have a solution to this problem :-(

Answer (score 2):

If your .c files are only produced by the .txt, then you can let the libmystuff.a depend on the txt, and evaluate the $(shell ls *.c) in the rule body instead.

Comment: Well, I need the makefile to actually compile the .c and elsewhere in the makefile, there are rule to indicate how to convert .c to .o with options and stuff and I don't want to have to repeat all that logic inside the libmystuff.a target.